# Changing UITableView to clear color

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I want my UITableView to be completely invisible but I have set a lot of things and nothing seems to be working.

I use custom table cells.

This is what I set in the cell.h

```
self.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
primaryLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
secondaryLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.accessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

And I also set

```
_tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

But still it is not working, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regards to the "incorrect" answer given, I think you mean is that you want the tableView background to disapear (showing the views background).

If so, in your viewDidLoad, add the following: (given you made your tableView programmatically)

```
[self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

If you also don't want to show the lines for each cell:

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead, you could use the hidden property of the tableView.

```
tableView.hidden = YES;
```